# Trying to center top DIV Bar

Tags: css

I have div bar that is set to not scroll so it will always show up on top of the website. Inside of this bar I have another div box that has two more buttons inside that are floated right so they are always on the top right.

The problem is I want the buttons to be centered top right not top right of the page. Instead if the body elements are centered the buttons would then be top right of the centered elements.

HERE IS THE CODE:

```
<DIV class="fixedtop">
        <div class="language2">
            <div class="english"> <font id="buttontxt">ENGLISH</font></div>

            <div class="spanish"> <font id="buttontxt">SPANISH</font></div>

        </div>
    </DIV>
```

Here is the CSS for the top bar:

```
   .fixedtop
{
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 0 auto;
    margin-right: 0 auto;
    top: 0px;
    width:600px;
    height: 30px;
}



.language2
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 0px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.spanish
{
    background-color:00ADEF;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 4px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height:30px;
    color:black;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 3px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    2px 3px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         2px 3px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}

.english
{
    background-color:00ADEF;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height:30px;
    color:black;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 3px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    2px 3px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         2px 3px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin-left` and `margin-right` accept only 1 parameter, not two as you're trying to pass in. Unfortunately, you can't use `margin: 0 auto` to centre a fixed element in CSS.

Hence, you have to set the `left` position to 50%, and then set the left margin to be negative half of the width of the element:

```
.fixedtop
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%
    width: 600px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: -300px;
}
```

Comment: So as long as I have a fixed width it should work? I had just put that in there to see. Is there a way to do it without a fixed width?

Comment: No, unfortunately there's no easy way to style a `div` element without an explicit width using only CSS. You could make a solution fairly simply using jQuery, though.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the following:

```
            .fixedtop
        {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
            left: 50%;
            margin: 0 0 0 -300px;
            width:600px;
            height: 30px;
            background: #060;
        }



        .language2
        {
            margin: 0 auto;
            background: #0F9;
        }
```

basically margin: auto doesn't work on position: fixed or absolute. so what we do is position it 50% from the left. And since we know the .fixedtop is 600px wide we give it a left margin of -300px to center it on the page again. Since .language2 is a block element (div) you do not need to give it a width and a height. and technically the margin: auto becomes obsolete as well. I gave both background colours just for the minute so that you can see their behaviour better. you can just delete them later. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You set this style for parent fixedtop

```
parentfixedtop{
 position:relative;
}
```